# Faye server is not launching or starting

Tags: ruby-on-rails, thin, faye

I'm following railscast and have followed the instructions exactly.  I've even used net.tutsplus's faye.ru code to set up the faye.ru file in the root directory.

Here's the faye.ru file:

```
require 'faye'
faye_server = Faye::RackAdapter.new(:mount => '/faye', :timeout => 45)
run faye_server
```

When I try to launch the server with `rackup faye.ru -s thin -E production`,

I get the following error:

```
/Users/TonyNg/faye-tutorial/faye.ru:3:in `block in <main>': undefined local variable or method ` ' for #<Rack::Builder:0x00000100918420 @ins=[]> (NameError)
    from /Users/TonyNg/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@rails313/gems/rack-1.3.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:51:in `instance_eval'
    from /Users/TonyNg/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@rails313/gems/rack-1.3.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:51:in `initialize'
    from /Users/TonyNg/faye-tutorial/faye.ru:1:in `new'
    from /Users/TonyNg/faye-tutorial/faye.ru:1:in `<main>'
    from /Users/TonyNg/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@rails313/gems/rack-1.3.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:40:in `eval'
    from /Users/TonyNg/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@rails313/gems/rack-1.3.5/lib/rack/builder.rb:40:in `parse_file'
    from /Users/TonyNg/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@rails313/gems/rack-1.3.5/lib/rack/server.rb:200:in `app'
    from /Users/TonyNg/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@rails313/gems/rack-1.3.5/lib/rack/server.rb:301:in `wrapped_app'
    from /Users/TonyNg/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@rails313/gems/rack-1.3.5/lib/rack/server.rb:252:in `start'
    from /Users/TonyNg/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@rails313/gems/rack-1.3.5/lib/rack/server.rb:137:in `start'
    from /Users/TonyNg/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@rails313/gems/rack-1.3.5/bin/rackup:4:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/TonyNg/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@rails313/bin/rackup:19:in `load'
    from /Users/TonyNg/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@rails313/bin/rackup:19:in `<main>'
```

It seems to just work for Ryan, but I'm out of luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution. I instead ran `rackup -s thin -E production config.ru` (**config.ru** instead of faye.ru) and got a working server consisting of:

```
>> Thin web server (v1.3.1 codename Triple Espresso)
>> Maximum connections set to 1024
>> Listening on 0.0.0.0:9292, CTRL+C to stop
```

Apparently, Rack's development middleware doesn't work with Thin async responses as I am using Thin in this app.

Comment: yes as documented here, https://github.com/faye/faye/issues/25
But have you or anyone found a way to use faye with sinatra in development mode so you have proper debug output ? I don't seem to find a way..